# Add public key to remote server authorized keys without saving file there

Tags: ssh, authorization

I'm trying to write a script to place my public key into the `authorized_keys` of a remote host, but I'm not sure how to do it without copying the file to the remote host or overwriting the `authorized_keys` already there.

The template of my script is basic:

```
#! /bin/bash

ssh user@host << EOF
    do stuff
EOF
```

If the file was on the remote host, I'd just do:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

But I want to do it without writing the file to the remote host.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reinvent [`ssh-copy-id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you already have a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with correct permissions etc.:

```
ssh user@host 'cat >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys' <~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Alternatively:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host
```

Comment: can I suggest adding a `~/` in front of the first command's `.ssh/authorized_keys`, just in case the user's profile runs a `cd` to somewhere else for some crazy reason?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I vaguely remember `~` being problematic with `ssh` for some roundabout reasons, but ok, I'll add it.

Comment: Is there any way to use `ssh-copy-id` to copy the key to a different directory on the remote server? Also is there a way to incorporate it into a script with other commands?

Comment: @Proletariat The point of `ssh-copy-id` is to "use locally available keys to authorise logins on a remote machine", thus no, it can't copy files elsewhere. As for "incorporating" it into a script, I can only presume it runs equally well when run from a script.

Comment: I tried `#! /bin/bash

ssh user@host 'cat >>/my/dir/.ssh/authorized_keys' <~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub << EOF
    touch hello
EOF` but it didn't execute my `touch`.